# can I pass an aspx page class to a subroutine?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Here's what I'd like to do: Let's say I have a page named "foo.aspx". The class is called "foo". On the page is a checkbox named "bar". I want a subroutine to update that checkbox.

So what I want to write is something like:

In foo.aspx.vb:

```
partial class foo
... whatever ...
dim util as new MyUtility
util.update_checkbox(me)
```

In MyUtility

```
public sub update_checkbox(foo1 as foo)
  foo1.bar.checked=true
end sub
```

But this doesn't work, as Visual Studio doesn't accept "foo" as a class name. Why not? Is there a magic namespace on it, or something else I have to do to identify the class besides say "foo"?

(And yes, I realize that in this trivial example, I could just pass in the checkbox, or move the one line of code into the aspx.vb, etc. My real problem involves setting a number of controls on the form, and I want to be able to do this in a class that has subtypes, so I can create an instance of the proper subtype, then just call one function and set all the controls differently depending on the subtype.)

*Update*

NDJ's answer works. For anyone else dropping by here, let me add that I was able to do something a little more flexible than his suggestion. I was able to create a property that returns the control itself, rather than some attribute of the control. Namely:

```
public interface ifoo
  readonly property bar_property as literal
end interface

partial class foo
  inherits system.web.page
  implements ifoo

  Public ReadOnly Property bar_property As Literal Implements ITest.bar_roperty
    Get
        ' assuming the aspx page defines a control with id "bar"
        Return bar
    End Get
  End Property
  ...
  dim util=new MyUtility()
  util.do_something(me)
  ...
end class

public class MyUtility
  public sub do_something(foo as IFoo)
    foo.bar_property.text="Hello world!"
    foo.bar_property.visible=true
  end sub
end class
```

This is a bit of a pain as you have to create an interface, and then create a property for each control that you want to be able to manipulate, but it does appear to work.

If there's a way to make the aspx class itself public, this is all unnecessary baggage in most cases. (It might be valuable if you have multiple pages that have controls that you want to manipulate in the same way.) But I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: When I try it, I can define a subroutine with a parameter of the type of a form in my VB.NET code. Your utility is in the same project?

Comment: I asked the question because each project has its own namespace (set in Properties | Application). If MyUtility is in a project with a different namespace, you would have to prepend the namespace for foo in the subroutine declaration.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Hmm, yes they're in the same project. Neither has a namespace attached. I tried "partial public class foo", but I still get an error trying to declare "foo1 as foo" in the subroutine. Is there a magic namespace attached to aspx pages or something? I see that if inside the page I write "dim x=me", that lets me hover on "me" in the VS debugger and then it shows the type as "ASP.foo_aspx". But trying to declare something as ASP.foo_aspx gives errors, too.

Comment: Hmmm. We don't see the same behavior. I assume that you searched "namespace" in your code and did not find any occurrence. In my own code, if I type "Me" in the code and hover on it, I just see the form name (e.g. frmReport). By the way, is your problem specific to that "foo" form or is it present with any form in your project? One thing I tried: I typed the namespace of the project, followed by the dot, and IntelliSense showed me the list of the forms in the project (among other things). You may try that, it may bring something to your attention.

Comment: Oops, I realize that you were talking about hovering at runtime. If I show "Me" in the debugger, I get the same thing as you: ASP.(foldername)_frmReport_aspx. But hovering on "Me" in the code shows only "frmReport".

Comment: @ConnorsFan I've tried several forms and the class name for none of them is recognized outside the class. Are you saying you can create foo.aspx, change the declartion to "public partial class foo", create some other vb file, and in that file write "x=new foo()" and it recognizes it no problem? Because it doesn't for me. I can refer to class foo within the class, but nowhere else, It's like it doesn't acknowledge the "public", or there's a magic namespace somewhere. btw what is the "namespace of a project"? Are you saying you get one automatically somewhere without actually declaring it?

Comment: I did not add "Public" to the partial class declaration. When I go to another form and say "Dim f as New frmReport()", it compiles without a problem. I am in VS 2010 and my project is an ASP.NET WebForms project (I first assumed that this was also your case but I don't know if ASP.NET MVC also has ASPX form files). For the moment, I cannot find a way to make the form class not visible in another one. As for the namespace of the project, I define it in (right click on the project in Solution Explorer) | Properties | Application. I think there is one by default but I can set it as I want.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Huh, that's fascinating. I'm running VS 2013 and this is a plain web forms project, and as I say, with or without the "public", the Intellisense doesn't list any forms outside the form itself, and if I type it anyway, it gives a compile error. And the properties page doesn't show a namespace. (I recall in 2010 you could specify a context name in project properties, an ability that for some reason was taken away in 2013. So maybe they removed a bunch of properties.) Well, thanks for your help. Creating an interface works, so I'm going that route rather than beating on this more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but there are a few hoops to jump through.
Using your example...
If you create an interface with a Boolean property, then implement it in your page, then you can pass the interface about and changing the property will automatically change the checkbox.  i.e.
interface:

```
Public Interface IFoo
    Property Bar As Boolean
End Interface
```

implementation:

```
Partial Class _Foo
    Inherits Page
    Implements IFoo

    Public Property Bar As Boolean Implements IFoo.Bar
        Get
            Return Me.CheckBox1.Checked
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            Me.CheckBox1.Checked = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Then some handler just needs to accept the interface:

```
Public Module SomeModule

    Public Sub SetValues(foo As IFoo)
        foo.Bar = True
    End Sub
End Module
```

and the caller from the page passes itself:

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SomeModule.SetValues(Me)
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the checkbox as a public property on the page.  I don't write in VB.net, but it would look something like this in C#:

Can someone convert this to VB.Net?

```
public bool MyCheckBoxSetting
{
    get { return mycheckbox.Checked; }
    set { mycheckbox.Checked = value; }
}
```

Comment: make your partial class public

Comment: @Duston How? I tried changing the declaration to "partial public class foo" and the class is still not recognized. Is there some special trick to making an aspx page class public?

Comment: If it's in the same project and name space, there's no magic.  If it's in the same project but different namespace, then you either have to fully qualify the class name or else add a "Using".  If the it's in a different project (even if it's in the same namespace) you need to add a reference to the assembly.